# Get a value of a particular cookie in Socket.io

Tags: cookies, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am using socket.io for real time message exchange in my application (most of the application is not written in node). I am looking for a way to get a value of particular cookie with Socket.io.

The closest I get so far is to use: `client.request.headers.cookie` which returns me a string:
`io=Ntp0MJVr3J_ifTKjAAAA; my_sess=c08mk6g0u66ifrjm6madt7535mknb7ur; other=fk1sq140hgj6gmp1vdcimkto71`.

I am not interested in all of these values and need only my_sess. Surely I can split and parse the string. It is not that hard and the most straightforward way is something like:

```
var value = cookieStr.split('my_sess=')[1].split('; ')[0];
```

But before doing this, I would rather ask if there is a native method to give me cookie value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [cookie](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cookie) -- a tiny module for cookie parsing and serialization:

```
npm install cookie
```

But if you're using Express framework you can `require` cookie module without installing it:

```
var cookie = require('express/node_modules/cookie');
```

Then use it:

```
var value = cookie.parse(cookieStr).my_sess;
```